# How can i use Firebase crashlytics in android studio offline mode

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

How can i use Firebase crashlytics in android studio offline mode
I was using firebase crash report.
Support will be discontinued in September and firebase crash will be upgraded to crashlytics.
Becuase I use android studio offline mode,
get the library from an internet computer and add it to app level build.gradle file
implementation files ('libs / fabric-1.4.2.aar')
implementation files ('libs / crashlytics-2.9.1.aar')
implementation files ('libs / answers-1.4.1.aar')
implementation files ('libs / crashlytics-core-2.4.1.aar')
implementation files ('libs / beta-1.2.7.aar')
.
(classpath and apply plugin are not used because it is in offline mode.)

If I run it like this, will get an error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:235)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:209)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
    at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
```

I must use offline mode.
Please, help.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Have you tried using --offline? If so, what happens after the initial gradle pull to get the dependencies.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thank you for answer.
How do I use --offline? I build with Android Studio. offlinemode is already checked.

Comment: It's a command line build argument for when building with Gradle. If you're using Android Studio and Gradle with offline mode disabled, then did you pull in the dependencies with a connection?

Comment: An internet connection is not available. TT So you can import the aar and jar files from an external PC that has Internet access.

Comment: You would need to get the AARs first, then important and run an offline gradle sync.

Comment: I have gradle-1.25.4.jar, fabric-1.4.3.aar, crashlytics-2.9.3.aar, answers-1.4.2.aar, crashlytics-core-2.6.3.aar, beta-1.2.8.aar files. And already applied 
implementation files ('libs / fabric-1.4.2.aar') 
implementation files ('libs / crashlytics-2.9.1.aar') 
implementation files ('libs / answers-1.4.1.aar') 
implementation files ('libs / crashlytics-core-2.4.1.aar') 
implementation files ('libs / beta-1.2.7.aar') 
in gradle file.

Comment: That should be fine then. Can you add your app's build.gradle and Fabric init code?

Comment: Email sent. please check.

Comment: solved it! add <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id" translatable="false">~~~~~</string> in strings.xml.  Thanks @MikeBonnell

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. For more docs on that: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#gradle-advanced-setup